# jQuery form.serialize() not giving the current values

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, serialization, extjs

I have this function that should submit the serialized values from my form.
Using `document.getElementById(form_id)` I get the correct form and values, if I serialize this form with `data = $(form).serialize();` the values are not correct.
The answers ot other questions suggest the name or the field being disabled being the cause, but that is not the case here.

Here my function with the results form the console.log.

```
var submit_form = function(form_id){
    form = document.getElementById(form_id);
    console.log(16, form);
    data = $(form).serialize();
    console.log(17, data);
    url = "/routmeda/checklist/" + form_id
    $.post( url, data, function( data ) {storeLogo.reload();} );
  }
```

The checkbox "aanvraagformulier" is unchecked.

Here the output on the console from line 16, correct

[image]

And here from line 17, serialize says the checkbox is on, which is the situation when the form was loaded.
[image]

How do I get the correct serilization ?

Comment: Is there any other same checkbox in the form with the same name? I heard somewhere checkboxes are not exactly passed correctly through `serialize()` function.

Comment: Are you checking the checkbox with javascript or manually in the browser? If you're using javascript, can we see the code that does that?

Comment: by clicking in the browser and it is the only field or checkbox with that name

Comment: Can't repro: http://jsbin.com/rowadekoca/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Can you tell us how to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @PraveenKumar when I try this at the samples online like your jsbin this works correctly, this is very difficult to reproduce online

Comment: I think you are mis-interpreting what you are seeing with inspect element. For example, go here: https://jsfiddle.net/gsba94qn/ inspect the checkbox, then check and uncheck it. you will not see the element become "checked" or "unchecked" in the inspect element window.

Comment: It's more likely that the value isn't what you expect it to be, rather than .serialize not working properly.

Comment: @KevinB I'm aware of that and I don't use inspect, but I uncheck it manually and submit, the checkbox is unchecked in the browser and in the object logged in console but not when I pass it through jQuery's serialize, it is like he looks at the value instead of at checked, I added a value attribute also but that doesn't change the result

Comment: `console.log(18,document.getElementsByName('aanvraagformulier').length, document.getElementsByName('aanvraagformulier')[0].checked);`

Comment: gives 18 0 false no matter if it is checked in the browser or not

Comment: this is a dynamical loaded form and it seems the problem is there only after the form is closed and loaded again, it seems as if the previous form is still there, I'm trying now to clear the form after closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by destroying the ExtJs window in which the form was displayed, it seems like the close button on this windows didn't do that before.
The `document.getElementById(form_id);` gave the value of the current window/form while jQuery's selector gave the ghost version of that window/form.
I didn't think it was a ExtJs problem otherwise I would have included that in my question. Thanks for the suggestions.